# How Common Name in self-signed certificat works?

Tags: linux, https, openssl, openshift, self-signed

I've to  create a vault with an https acces on a CRC OpenShift cluster ( 192.168.130.11 is the IP of the CodeReady Containers virtual machine) .

So I'm here in order to have some precisions about the **CN** in a self-signed certificat.

In order to create a certificat, I used these commands :

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365000 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 365000  -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem
```

For this command :

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
```

Some informations are necessary :

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:XX
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:XXX
Locality Name (eg, city) []:XXX
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:XXX
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:XXX
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:foo1
```

For the next command :

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365000 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
```

I've to put the same informations. But between this command and the previous command, if I put the same **CN** I will have an error.

So can you tell me what is the difference between the **CN** in this case ?

Which informations I've to put in the first **CN** and in the second **CN** ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In the first command, you are generating the **CA Certificate** and in the second command you are generating a **Server Certificate** using the CA you created before.

These cannot have the same Common Name, as the CA should be different from the server.